# Is there any way to add edit/delete button in each row for DHTMLX grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, dhtmlx

I am working on DHTMLX grid and i need to add edit/delete button in each row, Is there any way to do it. I googled it and i was able to find about check box and link.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom column type with any needed html-content.
For example, the following code will create an eXcell which will render the cell value as a button with a label:

```
   function eXcell_button(cell){ //the eXcell name is defined here
        if (cell){                // the default pattern, just copy it
            this.cell = cell;
            this.grid = this.cell.parentNode.grid;
        }
        this.edit = function(){}  //read-only cell doesn't have edit method
        this.isDisabled = function(){ return true; } // the cell is read-only, so it's always in the disabled state
        this.setValue=function(val){
            this.setCValue("<input type='button' value='"+val+"'>",val);                                      
        }
    }
    eXcell_button.prototype = new eXcell; // nests all other methods from the base class
```

all you need after that is to set your column type in your grid:

```
grid.setColTypes("button,...");
```

Here you can find a detailed tutorial with various examples:
http://docs.dhtmlx.com/grid__columns_types.html#customeditors